# Spring-Kafka: Impact of Consumer Group Rebalancing on Stateful Retry

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

If using `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` with stateful retry, such that the message is polled from the broker for each retry, there is a risk that for a long retry period that a consumer group rebalance could cause the partition to be re-assigned to another consumer.  Hence the stateful retry period/attempts would be reset, as the new consumer has no knowledge of the state of the retry.

Taking an example, if a retry max period was 24 hours, but consumer group re-balancing was happening on average every 12 hours, the retry could never complete, and the message (and those behind it) would eventually expire from the topic once they exceeded the retention period.  (Assuming the cause of the retryable exception was not resolved in this time).  The message would not end up on the DLT after 24 hours as expected, as retries would not be exhausted due to the reset.

I assume that even if a consumer is retrying by re-polling messages, there is no guarantee that following a re-balance that this consumer would retain assignment to this partition.  Or is it the case that we can be confident that so long as this consumer instance is alive that it would typically retain assignment to the partition it is polling?

Are there best practises/guidelines on use of stateful retry to cater for this?

Stateless retry means any total retry time that exceeds the poll timeout would cause rebalancing and duplicate message delivery.  To avoid that then the retry period must be very limited.  Or is the guideline to allow this, ensure messages are deduplicated by the consumer, so that the duplicate messages are acceptable and long running stateless retries can be configured?

Is the only safe and stable option for enabling a retry period of something like several hours (e.g. to cater for a service being unavailable for this period) to use retry topics?

Thanks,
Rob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of stateful retry was to avoid a rebalance; without it, the consumer would be delayed up to the aggregate of all retry attempt delays.

However, retry in the listener adapter (including stateful retry) has now been deprecated because the error handler can now do everything the `RetryTemplate` can do (back off, exception classification, etc, etc).

With stateful retry (or backoffs in the error handler), the longest back off must be less than `max.poll.interval.ms`.

A 24 hour backoff is, frankly, ridiculous - it would be better to just stop the container and restart it a day later.

Comment: Thanks Gary.

Mine was a long and rambling question.  I guess to ask the main bit more succinctly:

If a consumer instance is performing a stateful retry, and a new consumer instance is added to the consumer group causing a rebalance, is it guaranteed, or likely, or chance, that the same consumer instance will continue polling the message (and hence keep track of the stateful retry period/attempts)?

Comment: Adding a new consumer will only cause a rebalance if the retry backoff exceeds `max.poll.interval.ms`, which you should never do. It is not guaranteed; you can, however, use a custom `ConsumerPartitionAssignor`; there are also "Sticky" assignors which attempt to preserve the existing state. As I said, stateful retry is deprecated. Don't use it.

Comment: Yes, I am not using the RetryTemplate.  I am using SeekToCurrentErrorHandler with FixedBackOff.

Your docs state:

"_the use of stateful retry, via the listener adapter retry configuration, is no longer necessary. You can provide the same functionality with appropriate configuration of the error handler_"

Hence I have still been describing it as stateful retry as its the same functionality (re-polling from broker between retries, tracking retry attempts/period), as a means to distinguish it from stateless retry.

Maybe I should describe it as Error Handler Backoff Retry.

Comment: Yes; stateful retry is a specific capability of the `RetryTemplate` so using that term in this context was confusing.